# distance matrix calculation and hierarchical clustering for large number of observations and dimensions in R

Tags: r, performance, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I'm trying to do hierarchical clustering on large datasets in `R`, e.g. > 30,000 rows (observations) and > 30 columns (variables). Clustering itself goes pretty quickly with the `fastcluster` package. However, I'm running into memory and speed problems due to the dissimilarity calculations. This only works up to 10,000-15,000 observations. For higher numbers, `R` usually crashes. And even if the dissimilarity matrix is calculated, I get a `memory overflow` error when I try to cluster afterwards. Is there a way to overcome these problems?

I'm using Windows 7 Professional on a 64-bit machine with 4 GB RAM.

MWE:

```
library('fastcluster')
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(900000), nrow = 30000))
dissim <- dist(df)
hr <- hclust(dissim)
```

Comment: Maximum RAM usage on my system was 10 GB with this, but trying to plot the result terminated the R session.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `fastcluster` you can use the `hclust.vector` function which is far less memory-intensive than `hclust` (See the `fastcluster` [paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v53/i09/paper) for details).

Answer (score 1):

Could be worth looking into GPU processing
http://www.r-tutor.com/gpu-computing/clustering/distance-matrix

Answer (score 1):

You should consider approximate solutions and better clustering algorithms.

It's fairly easy to see that anything based on the distance matrix needs at least `O(n^2)` memory and runtime. In fact, some linkage criterions can only be computed in `O(n^3)` time.

100.000 instances with double precision need ~80 GB RAM, by exploiting symmetry you can cut this into half; but likely the algorithm needs to make a copy and add some scratch space...

With 4 GB, of which probably at least 1 is already used up, I'm not surprised to see this limit drop to some 20000 enties. 8 bytes * 20.000 * 20.000 * 2 copies is 6.4 GB

For clustering large data sets, look for algorithms that **do not need a distance matrix**. And for good performance, use something that has linear runtime (k-means for example, while you might as well just use a sample of your data, scales linear) or use an index structure to accelerate it. DBSCAN for example will in a good implementation (the R `fpc` implementation I know is *not* good) be able to exploit index structures and then run in  `O(n log n)` time. With a good implementation, this will easily be 100x faster on this size of data.

Comment: I've tried different `k-means` implementations, but the results are not satisfactory. I am looking for an unsupervised algorithm, so I don't want to set the number of clusters in advance. There is a fast implementation in the `Bioconductor` package `flowMeans`, but I'm not happy with the results. Can you recommend another one?

Furthermore, I don't see how I could draw a decent heatmap with non-hierarchical algorithms. Btw, sampling the data also leads to different heatmaps.

DBSCAN is a good point, thanks. However, I haven't found any other DBSCAN implementations in `R` rather than `fpc`.

Comment: R isn't very scalable or fast, for that matter. If you really need large data, try looking into other applications. I've used 100k elements with ELKI, and it was less than a minute total runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Dissimilarity matrix for 30000 elements will be 30000×30000 with double precision floating point taking up 8 bytes that's about 8 gigs. You cannot use these libraries as is at this scale with 4 gigs of RAM.

Comment: see post by mcastillion, fastcluster works without needing the entire N^2 matrix at once.  It would be good if more clustering packages allowed an option to call the dist(x,y) function for vectors instead of requiring it to be stored.